# getting date from database view with vb

Tags: vb.net, view

```
Public Function VW_hrm(ByVal hrm_id As Object, 
ByVal hrm_code As String, 
ByVal art_naam As String, 
ByVal grp_id As Object, 
ByVal mrk_id As Object, 
ByVal page As Long, 
ByVal pagesize As Long, 
Optional ByVal sortering As Object = 1) As DataSet

            Dim params(9) As Object

            params(0) = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session("AdministratieID")
            params(1) = art_id
            params(2) = art_code
            params(3) = art_naam
            params(4) = Nothing
            params(5) = ccInt(grp_id)
            params(6) = ccInt(mrk_id)
            params(7) = page
            params(8) = pagesize
            params(9) = ccInt(sortering)
            params(10) = 0

            Return GetData("SP_VW_hrm", params)

End Function
```

Comment: And what is your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the params to 10
like descrided here:

Dim params(10) As Object